# Where could I ask questions about power grids?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Would it be right to ask something about power grids at [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)? I'm interested in the history of the 345 kV voltage level.

My question relates to the following:

According to [this source](https://books.google.de/books?id=C5W8uxwMqdUC&pg=PA120) it was first applied in 1953 by American Electric Power, but much more is not available at the forefront of the internet. I would like to know where this line was, who has tried this and why e.g. Texas (ERCOT) still sticks to 345 kV as highest voltage, despite 500 kV would be much more economic.

Comment: FYI, that site has its own Meta as well where you could ask if your question is on-topic before posting. https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bart Not without some reputation there, though.

Comment: Ugh, you are absolutely correct @Catija. Didn't think about that.

Comment: @Bart You need 200 for the site bonus, but only 20 on any site to chat.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>(Obligatory disclaimer: I'm not a regular at any of the sites mentioned below; before asking a question, please read the [tour](/tour) and the [help center](/help) articles about asking questions on the site itself.)</sup>

Electrical Engineering seems to focus more on [practical questions about electronics on the 'micro'-level](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so it doesn't seem to be the right place for this question. The general Stack Exchange site about [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) does have a few questions about [electrical grids](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical-grid); not really many, but it's not a large site to begin with. It would be my first choice to ask such a question. If that doesn't work, the historical part of your question might be asked on [History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/), though the part about Texas is definitely off-topic there.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Now I've asked here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24347/whats-the-history-of-the-345-kv-voltage-level-in-power-transmission

Comment: Is it wrong to ask 2 questions at once?

Comment: Good luck! Sometimes, it's wrong; especially if both questions aren't really related, or by themselves already take a long post to answer. In this case, it's probably fine.